# Need Text to stay within the width of the image and wrap around

Tags: flutter

I have a column inside a listview.  The column has image at the top and text in the bottom.  I would like the text to stay within the width of the image and wrap.  Right now the text does not wrap.  Here is how the image and text in the column look like. Any body know how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code of the column:

```
Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: AppColors.pink2),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints:
                      BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300, maxWidth: width - 50),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    child: Image(
                      image: MemoryImage(chatMessageModel.rawData!),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                  child: Text('I need this text to wrap around'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexible with AutoSizeText Widget to make it possible.

- AutoSizeText Widget align your text size by corresponding your screen size
- Flexible Widget adjust your text position

Working code :

```
                                      Flexible(
                                        child: AutoSizeText(
                                          'I need this text to wrap around',
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0,
                                                1), //rankingNoColors(index)
                                            fontSize: 24.0,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
```

Comment: I don't want to resize the text size.  It should stay the same.

Comment: @AimnBlbol try with my code and please revert

Comment: Flexible made the image and text disappear.  I also added fit: FlexFit.loose, but did not work